# Building a set of AngularJS directives to provide the user information about their input

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I am trying to create an AngularJS directive that will give information to the user about the text they are inputting such as the number of characters they must or may enter and so on and so forth.

To cut a long story short, I would be very grateful if someone could help me **improve the javascript code for my directives**. As of now the only thing the directives do is **provide the user with the number of characters** in the textarea.

Code is hosted on Github and located in [this repository](https://github.com/balteo/angularjs-directives/tree/21c8ea4a22e161e53079f9a946b633b8b44cdd7c/app).

Here are my **directives**:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.directives', [])
    .directive('enhanced', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            controller: 'enhancedCtrl',
            scope: {},
            transclude: true,
            template: '<div ng-transclude></div>'
        };
    })
    .controller('enhancedCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        var info = function () {
            var size = 0;
            return {
                getSize: function () {
                    return size;
                },
                setSize: function (newSize) {
                    size = newSize;
                }
            };
        }();

        var callback;

        this.registerSizeChangedCallback = function (callback) {
            this.callback = callback;
        };
        this.notifyObserver = function () {
            this.callback();
        };
        this.setSize = function (size) {
            info.setSize(size);
            this.notifyObserver();
        };
        this.getSize = function () {
            return info.getSize();
        };
    }])
    .directive('enhancedTextarea', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^enhanced',
            scope: true,
            replace: true,
            template: '<textarea></textarea>',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, enhancedCtrl) {
                $scope.$watch($attrs.ngModel, function (newVal) {
                   enhancedCtrl.setSize(newVal.length);
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .directive('notice', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: '^enhanced',
            replace: true,
            scope: {},
            template: '<div>{{size}} characters</div>',
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, enhancedCtrl) {
                enhancedCtrl.registerSizeChangedCallback(function () {
                    $scope.size = enhancedCtrl.getSize();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

And my **html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div enhanced>
        <div enhanced-textarea ng-model="text"></div>
        <h3>{{text}}</h3>
        <div notice></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please provide feedback about both:

- **My usage of the AngularJS framework**
- **My usage of Javascript**

**edit**: I have greatly changed the api of my directive since my original post. Please have a look at the following [commit](https://github.com/balteo/angularjs-directives/tree/3624e0743d83d749c7629e448eba5ceeffd1c44d). I am looking for people willing to help me on this "lone-directive" open-source projet... Everyone welcome!

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of one of your own questions. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42543/simplifying-an-angularjs-directive-that-counts-the-number-of-characters-entered If you have new info to add to the question you could simply edit it.

Comment: Does your code here reflect the last change?